# Override CSS using Media queries struggle

Tags: html, css, media-queries, overriding

I have been searching high & low round the web, especially on Stack Overflow and I am still having some problems overriding my base CSS styles with the `@media queries`.

Firstly, my website is a custom theme I developed to use with WordPress (not that it should make a difference).

Heres the setup...

### File: styles.css

1. I import my other CSS styles at the top of the file - this is including my `mobile.css` file which is where I override the base styles.
2. Then the default CSS styles are defined.

---

```
#main-nav .nav-wrapper{
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
width: 594px;
}

#main-nav{
background-color: #F1F5C8;
padding: 10px 0;
}

#main-nav .border-image-left{
float: left;
width: 37px;
height: 43px;
background-image: url('images/navi_left_border.png');
}

#main-nav .border-image-right{
float: left;
width: 37px;
height: 43px;
background-image: url('images/navi_right_border.png');
}

#main-nav ul{
float: left;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
width: 520px;
height: 43px;
line-height: 43px;
background-color: #DBEA99;
}

#main-nav ul li{
float: left;
display: block;
text-align: center;
padding: 0 20px;
width: 130px; /* fallback for non-calc() browsers */
width: calc( 100% / 4 );
}

#main-nav a, #main-nav a:visited{
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
color: #06421A;
}

#main-nav ul li a:hover{
opacity: 0.6;
}
```

File: mobile.css

```
@media screen and ( min-width: 511px ) and ( max-width: 620px ){

/*****************/
/** Navigation **/
/***************/

#main-nav{
padding: 0;
}

#main-nav .nav-wrapper{
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
width: inherit;
}

#main-nav ul{
width: 100%;
height: 53px;
line-height: 53px;
}

#main-nav .border-image-left, #main-nav .border-image-right{
width: 0;
height: 0;
background-image: none;
display: none;
}

#main-nav ul li{
padding: 0;
width: auto;
margin: 0;
}
}
```

So if you can see anything that I have done incorrect or any suggestion for me to try it would be much appreciated. Been at this issue all week!

P.s: I import the mobile.css file with other styles at the beginning of my style.css file AND other override's seem to work fine but not this bit.

*Let me know if you'd like to see the live version for clarification of code...*

Comment: Do you include the `mobile.css` last?

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle(It makes easier to solve the problem).

Comment: Are you testing on a mobile phone or simply re-sizing your viewport window? if first case is true, then consider checking for `viewport` meta tag, otherwise, consider @Thaillie's question.

Comment: @Thaillie Yes, this is the last of my imports, however I import them all at the top of the file. Another thing I should have mentioned is that I am able to override other CSS styles in this mobile.css, but this navigation part seems to not.

Comment: @AdamAzad I am testing both

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Please include your HTML

Comment: Can you include the link to the live version? @Samuroid

Comment: @AdamAzad Live version: www.alyazmalim.co.uk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes down with the order of your including CSS files `mobile.css`. Here's the order. The first file is `style.css`, then `mobiel.css` included/imported via `style.css` as below.

```
@import "style/css/mobile.css";
```

The CSS is not mobile-first. Instead, targets device width using `max-width` and `min-width`.

[image][image]

Since `mobile.css` loaded before the rest of of `style.css` properties, its properties are being overridden by `style.css` regardless of width (I believe this is caused by `media="screen"` attribute)

You could make your CSS mobile-first, meaning that all properties are optimized for mobile, then as the screen gets wider, you apply tablets, and desktop optimized CSS for elements. It's laborious. Best solution is to load `mobile.css` after `style.css` like below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://alyazmalim.co.uk/wp-content/themes/alyazmalim/style.css" type="text/css"> <!-- remove media attribute or set it to "all" -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://alyazmalim.co.uk/wp-content/themes/alyazmalim/style/css/mobile.css" type="text/css">
```